# Android, how to pull images from a photosharing site

Tags: javascript, android, photo-gallery, photos, pull

I am trying to pull images from a URl of a photosharing site like Picasa. I would like to be able to define a URL and enable swipe functionality to switch through the different photos. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Photosharing site like Picasa provides web service, You will have to go through their documentation as to see how to construct the url,

Genrally response will be in the form of XML or JSON, parse it to get image urls, Then 
in Android code, use the images in Gallery view or view flipper.

Comment: That is an amazing comment, or answer. I am comfortable enough with my coding ability to say that that is out of my league. How about adding a photo to an ImageView? Would I add a photo to the res file where it will draw from?

Comment: Yes if you want to start in simple terms, you can do that, have 4-5 images in res/drawable folder, use image view and some left and right navigation button, on click of buttons, change the image view source.

Comment: What type of drawable folder would this be? Would I make a new one?

Comment: Okay, I just made a new drawable folder without any further hdpi stuff or anything. I have got it to work nicely... thank you much.

Comment: I am still interested in finding out how to add some left and right navigation. I have enough images to desire this functionality